# Preview button doesn't appear on SDTT for "Physician" until I remove "WebApplication"

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets-tool

My site is an online clinic management application, so in a doctor profile page I have 4 items: `WebApplication`, `WebPage`, `BreadcrumbList`, `Physician`.

[image]

The problem is I cannot see "Physician" preview button until I remove  the `WebApplication` item!

[image]

Is there any conflicts between these structured data items?

[You can see the testing tools result here](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fboghrat.com%2Fdr%2Fm-sarrafan).